# Better wifi strength meter?

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome-os, wifi-driver, chromebook

Is there a way to better visualize my wifi signal strength?  I get that the icon with the bars is sufficient for most people, but I want to know how much is noise, how much is signal, and generally a finer-grained resolution so I can see the effect of different surroundings and materials.

If I knew how to access this data I might want to plot it or make a list of places that get really good signals, etc.  Maybe make a browser extension or some other app so I can visualize the signals around me.

I'm interested in general answers (what you should look for regardless of operating system/hardware) as well as more specific answers.  My specific hardware is a Samsung ARM Chromebook + Chrome OS (or sometimes Ubuntu Linux).

Comment: I am not aware of programs which work on ChromeOS, however I wanted to mention these points:

 1. How much 'one bar' is depends on the driver. The same signal strength might be indicated by 2 out of 5 bars on on device, and by 4 out of 5 on another device. Basically you can not rely on it except as an indication of 'probably very poor' or 'probably very good'
 2. For windows try [inSSIDer](http://www.metageek.net/products/inssider/).

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to Xirrus Wi-Fi Inspector, the best windows based signal meter i have used up till now, gives you upload download speed, noise, the exact speed you are getting and much more- This wifi Radar/ Wi-Fi Inspector shows you even more detailed information about the network to which you're currently connected, including your internal IP address, external IP address, DNS and gateway information, and so on.

you can [download this from here](http://www.xirrus.com/Products/Wi-Fi-Inspector)

but frankly speaking , nothing  can match the iOS wi-fi utilities like SpeedTestX , Network analyzer,